# PostMan gives "JSONError: Unexpected token '<' at 1:1 <!DOCTYPE html> ^ " when trying to extract data from response body

Tags: api-testing, rest-api, postman

I am trying to chain API request on using POSTMAN. I am writing a script in the test section for extracting token from the response body and storing it in an environment variable. 
This is my code in the test section:

```
var jsonObject = xml2Json(responseBody);
let firstresponse= pm.response.json().results[0];
let token = firstresponse.token;
pm.environment.set("token1", token);
```

However, when i run the request, i am getting multiple errors like

```
JSONError: Unexpected token '<' at 1:1 <!DOCTYPE html> ^
```

or

```
Unexpected '<'
```

or

```
Unexpected token u
```

I tried googling it, and many have experience similar problems, but none the solution helped me. Is it a bug in Postman or is their any workaround? Anybody has any solutions. I am using POSTMAN Version 6.2.0-canary01.

Comment: Which line produces the error message?

Comment: Looks like your response is not a JSON string but HTML. Could be you get an error page (f.i. http error). What is your complete respons?

Comment: @Patrick I am getting the proper response of the login page,but in HTML. It can be converted to XML by selecting the option provided there. But when I chose JSON in that list, Unexpected '<' appears.

Comment: @AlexeyR. I am not sure which line produces the error. Because it just gives Unexpected '<' in response body in JSON format

Comment: Do you still require help with this problem?

Comment: I eventually figured a workaround, but any help is appreciated for future @DannyDainton

Comment: I too was facing the same issue can you please tell me the workaround what you figured out.

Comment: @Ranga The workaround was I stopped using Postman and started using Swagger and SoapUI. By doing this I was able to do a lot more than I could ever do with Postman.

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65642938) helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in postman:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setGlobalVariable("token1",(jsonData.results[0].token));
```

This is an example where you get the token from your JSON reponse and set it in a Global Variable. You can just change it to environment also if you like.

More info about test scripts in postman: https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test_examples/

Comment: I tried this suggestion - and got two or three errors instead of just one.